# How to access the respective component from the outer element?

Tags: angular

I have an component with the following template:

```
<div (click)="changeValue(comp)" *ngFor="let type of types">
  <div [ngSwitch]="type">
    <app-a #comp [value]="'a'" *ngSwitchCase="'a'"></app-a>
    <app-b #comp [value]="'b'" *ngSwitchCase="'b'"></app-b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside the `changeValue` I want to have access to the respective component (here `a` or `b` but there could be more).
For example:

```
changeComp(comp: any) {
  comp.value = 'new value'
}
```

I tried the followings: (they both work but I'd like a better solution):

1. Passing an `id` to the `changeValue` function and adding an `id` property to each component (using the index from foreach). This works but the problem is that I don't want component `a` or `b` to have an `id` property, it feels like a workaround and not a solution. Instead of an `id` property I tried using an `id` attribut, but inside the `change value` I can't associate the `id` attribute with the component because `@ViewChildren` can't get both `elementRef` and `componentRef`.
2. Combining component `a` and `b` into a general component to remove the switch. The problem is that there are cases when It's better to have separate components.

Here is a working stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxc8nc

Comment: "I want changeValue to change the value property of the corresponding (a or b) component." From what? To what? Corresponding to what?

Comment: I updated my answer, if you still don't understand what I want to achieve, check the stackblitz example. I think its pretty obvious what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can add value property to you type object and bind it like code below:

```
<div #parent (click)="changeValue(type.value)" *ngFor="let type of types">
  Click
  <div [ngSwitch]="type.t">
    <input #case_a [(ngModel)]="type.value" *ngSwitchCase="'a'" />
    <input #case_b [(ngModel)]="type.value" *ngSwitchCase="'b'" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This way type.value will always have value from whatever visible child component.
Here I created an example on how this works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bph8z3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my answer to clarify what I want. Please check my stackblitz to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: This is just a simplified example, in my case want to be able to change properties that are not even declared as @Input(). I want to have access to the component, so I can change what I want. Is this a solution for that? Sorry if this is not clear from my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hidden] instead of ngSwitch so that you still have access to the child component event when it is not displayed, this will prevent you getting undefined.

```
    <app-a #comp [value]="'a'" [hidden]="type !== 'a'"></app-a>
    <app-b #comp [value]="'b'" [hidden]="type !== 'b'"></app-b>
```

You could call a method on the child component directly using ViewChild.

```
@ViewChild('componentA') a: ComponentA;
@ViewChild('componentb') b: Componentb;
```

Then target the one you want based upon your conditions and call a method on the child to update the value.

```
if(a) {
a.updateValue(value)
}
else if(b) {
b.updateValue(value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my answer to clarify what I want. Please check my stackblitz to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You could use [hidden] instead of ngSwitch as this would give you access to the component and prevent you getting undefined. I have edited my answer to show this, hope it helps.